# Segmentation fault in QGraphicsView::setScene()

Tags: graphics, qt4

I have a normal widget application which should show a finite automata in a graphic view widget. I add a QGgraphicsView to the main window, which has an instance of QGraphicsScene:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    scene(new QGraphicsScene(this))
{
    setupUi(this);
    scene->addText("Hello");
    ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene); // bumb!
}
```

Program crashes by a segmentation fault when it tries to set scene for graphicsView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose between inheriting from the ui class and having a ui member.

Then the code should be either:

```
ui->setupUi(this);
...
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

or:

```
setupUi(this);
...
graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Comment: I just noticed that the new version of QtCreator follows second way. Removing `ui->` solved the problem. Thanks :)